# reflecting graphs in lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble reflecting graphs in lines. For example, I know that reflecting a graph in the line $ y = x$ would mean all x values of my original graph would become the y values. But how do you sketch a reflection of a graph without having to plot points. I noticed many people in my class are able to just look at the original graph, look at the line we have to reflect in and just draw it. Whereas, I have to plot points so that I can get a general idea of what the graph is doing before I actually draw the graph.

Comment: One trick you can use is to rotate your paper (on which the original graph and the line of reflection are drawn) until the line of reflection is vertical. Then, you're just drawing the mirror image of the original graph, which I think is reasonably intuitive for us.